# Ignoring a parameter if certain valuein Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines

First question on Stack Overflow, apologies for any etiquette faux pas.

We have an Azure Pipeline for application delivery where the engineer or developer can select the environment the app gets deployed to. I'll change some of the identifying info, but looks something like this:

```
parameters: 

    - name: environment
      type: string
      default: none (build app only)
      values:
      - none (build app only)
      - test
      - preprod
      - prod
```

'none (build app only)' is for our CI stages. And our CD stage that looks something like this:

```
- stage: DeployToKubernetes
  condition: ne('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'none (build app only)')
  pool: $(buildpool)
  jobs:
  - template: <template>.yaml
    parameters:
      ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
        ${{ parameter.Key }}: ${{ parameter.Value }} 
      AppName: ${{ variables.solutionName }} 
      k8sServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-k8s'
      ServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-sc'
```

This all works as expected when deploying to our environments but when selecting 'none (build app only)' as the environment, it errors.

I get errors as soon as I run the Pipeline such as:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job <template>.job: Step input
> azureSubscription references service connection none (build app
> only)-sc which could not be found.

From what I can tell, this *seems* to be due to the fact that the ADO is validating the parameters passed to the stage before assessing the condition. My thought process was that if the condition for the stage isn't met, then ADO won't validate the underpinning jobs, but I think I'm missing something.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

I've tried reversing the condition statement and cloning the stage with the condition being if environment DOES eq an environment, and still get the issue.

EG:

```
- stage: DeployToKubernetes
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'preprod')
  pool: $(buildpool)
  jobs:
  - template: <template>
    parameters:
      ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
        ${{ parameter.Key }}: ${{ parameter.Value }} 
      AppName: ${{ variables.solutionName }} 
      k8sServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-k8s'
      ServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-sc'
```

Will still fail with the same message when selecting 'none' as the environment.

Also tried having the parameter value as 'none' instead of 'none (build app only)'.
I've tried defining a variable that assesses the value of the parameter and using that variable as the condition (in case it's runtime / compile time issues).
I've tried changing

> condition: ne('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'none (build app only)')

to

> condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'none (build app only)'))

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Hi AllTheGearNoIde, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the problem is that the service connection used for the task is evaluated and approved at compile time (when the pipeline is queued), but the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions) is only evaluated at run time (when you reach the task). As an alternative, have you considered using an [if expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions#conditionally-run-a-step) to conditionally include/exclude the stage at compile time?

Comment: @VinceBowdren that did the trick, thank you!

I managed to add a conditional to the job in the stage, not the stage itself and that works. I'll be trying different syntaxes against the stage later this week when I have some time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Grand; I've written up the advice as a proper answer, for the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the service connection used for the task is evaluated and approved at compile time (when the pipeline is queued), but the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions) is only evaluated at run time (immediately before the task is run).

As an alternative, I'd suggest using an [if expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions#conditionally-run-a-step) to conditionally exclude the entire stage at compile time:

```
${{ if ne(parameters.environment, 'none (build app only)' }}:
  - stage: DeployToKubernetes
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'preprod')
    pool: $(buildpool)
    jobs:
    - template: <template>
      parameters:
        ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
          ${{ parameter.Key }}: ${{ parameter.Value }} 
        AppName: ${{ variables.solutionName }} 
        k8sServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-k8s'
        ServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.environment }}-sc'
```